# SQL - Extract JSON from Array

Tags: sql, arrays, json, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I'm writing some queries with Google BigQuery. I want to extract the JSON from an array. Somehow I can extract it. And @Mikhail Berlyant helped me [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53368435/bigquery-unnest-an-array-getting-dupliates/53368514#53368514). But now the problem is in extracting JSON from the array without Duplicates.

### Current Structure:

[image]

### I what I tried:

```
WITH
  cte AS (
  SELECT
    labels,
    cost
  FROM
    BILLING.gcp_billing_export_v1)
SELECT
  la,
  cost
FROM
  cte,
  UNNEST(labels) AS la
```

[image]

See the cost box, the COST value is repeated twice, because we have 2 KEY, VALUE pairs in the array.

So while doing `sum(cost)` with the group by `la.key` then I'm getting the wrong value.

### What Im looking for is,

[image]

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: So you just don't want the cost to be repeated?

Comment: Yes Khan, I don't cost to be repeated

Comment: Your keys of `department` and `hrd` are uniform across the dataset?

Comment: No, its has different value on some rows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT 
  description, 
  ARRAY(
    SELECT AS STRUCT 
      JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(kv, '$.key') key, 
      JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(kv, '$.value') value 
    FROM UNNEST(SPLIT(labels, '},{')) kv_temp, 
    UNNEST([CONCAT('{', REGEXP_REPLACE(kv_temp, r'^\[{|}]$', ''), '}')]) kv
  ) labels,
  cost
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

You can test, play with above using excerpt of dummy data from your question as below

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 'aaa' description, '[{"key":"application","value":"scaled-server"},{"key":"department","value":"hrd"}]' labels, 0.323316 cost UNION ALL
  SELECT 'bbb' description, '[{"key":"application2","value":"scaled-server2"},{"key":"department2","value":"hrd2"}]' labels, 0.342825 cost 
)
SELECT 
  description, 
  ARRAY(
    SELECT AS STRUCT 
      JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(kv, '$.key') key, 
      JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(kv, '$.value') value 
    FROM UNNEST(SPLIT(labels, '},{')) kv_temp, 
    UNNEST([CONCAT('{', REGEXP_REPLACE(kv_temp, r'^\[{|}]$', ''), '}')]) kv
  ) labels,
  cost
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

with result

```
Row description labels.key      labels.value    cost     
1   aaa         application     scaled-server   0.323316     
                department      hrd      
2   bbb         application2    scaled-server2  0.342825     
                department2     hrd2
```

Comment: Thanks for your amazing queries, it works, but while apply the same query on my actual dataset im getting this error `No matching signature for function SPLIT for argument types: ARRAY<STRUCT<key STRING, value STRING>>, STRING. Supported signatures: SPLIT(STRING, [STRING]); SPLIT(BYTES, BYTES) at [20:17]` .  Line 20 is `    FROM UNNEST(SPLIT(labels, '},{')) kv_temp, 
`

Comment: in  your question you provided example of data - see `Current Structure` section. so my answer is based on what you provided in the question

Comment: I used `TO_JSON_STRING(labels)` to get that column. Is that fine?

Comment: I changed it to  `FROM UNNEST(SPLIT(TO_JSON_STRING(labels), '},{')) kv_temp` . now its working

Comment: Hey @Mikhail, If I want to do group by 1,2 3 for sum (c0st) how this works?

Comment: you should post new question and provide all details of what you need including input data and expected output - this will allow us to answer your new question

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53382005/bigquery-group-by-on-arrays

Comment: Thanks! this save my time.