# BigQuery - Group by on arrays

Tags: arrays, group-by, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I want to group by on an array.

sample query:

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 'compute' description, '[{"key":"application","value":"scaled-server"},{"key":"department","value":"hrd"}]' labels, 0.323316 cost UNION ALL
  SELECT 'compute' description, '[{"key":"application","value":"scaled-server"},{"key":"department","value":"hrd"}]' labels, 0.342825 cost 
)
SELECT 
  description, 
  ARRAY(
    SELECT AS STRUCT 
      JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(kv, '$.key') key, 
      JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(kv, '$.value') value 
    FROM UNNEST(SPLIT(labels, '},{')) kv_temp, 
    UNNEST([CONCAT('{', REGEXP_REPLACE(kv_temp, r'^\[{|}]$', ''), '}')]) kv
  ) labels,
  cost
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

Result of the above query:

```
Row description labels.key      labels.value    cost     
1   compute         application     scaled-server   0.323316     
                    department      hrd      
2   compute         application    scaled-server  0.342825     
                    department     hrd
```

I want result like below:

```
Row description labels.key      labels.value    cost     
1   compute         application     scaled-server   0.666141     
                    department      hrd
```

Comment: what is the logic of grouping? is it - all keys and values should be the same in order to be grouped?

Comment: I just updated the question, the intention is, the description column has what service is this like VM, cloudSQL, BQ 
and the label column has tell us the information about the labels like vm labels (env=prod) SO, end of the day if I want to get  cost for compute or vm which has the env=staging . Thats why I need to group by on DESCRIPTION first then key values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 'compute' description, '[{"key":"application","value":"scaled-server"},{"key":"department","value":"hrd"}]' labels, 0.323316 cost UNION ALL
  SELECT 'compute' description, '[{"key":"application","value":"scaled-server"},{"key":"department","value":"hrd"}]' labels, 0.342825 cost 
), temp AS (
  SELECT description, labels, SUM(cost) AS cost
  FROM `project.dataset.table`
  GROUP BY description, labels
)
SELECT 
  description, 
  ARRAY(
    SELECT AS STRUCT 
      JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(kv, '$.key') key, 
      JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(kv, '$.value') value 
    FROM UNNEST(SPLIT(labels, '},{')) kv_temp, 
    UNNEST([CONCAT('{', REGEXP_REPLACE(kv_temp, r'^\[{|}]$', ''), '}')]) kv
  ) labels,
  cost
FROM temp
```