# BigQuery: Select most recent of group of rows with ARRAY type field

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a table with 3 columns: String, Datetime, ARRAY().

```
Name  |       LastLogin       | FavoriteNumbers
Paul  | "2019-03-03T06:29:35" | (1, 3, 6, 8)
Paul  | "2019-03-03T02:29:35" | (1, 3, 6, 8)
Paul  | "2019-03-01T01:29:35" | (1, 3, 6, 8)
Anna  | "2019-03-03T02:29:35" | (1, 2, 3, 4)
Anna  | "2019-03-03T01:29:35" | (1, 2, 3, 4)
Maya  | "2019-03-02T10:29:35" | (9, 11, 13, 8)
```

This is the result I want:

```
Paul  | "2019-03-03T06:29:35" | (1, 3, 6, 8)
Anna  | "2019-03-03T02:29:35" | (1, 2, 3, 4)
Maya  | "2019-03-02T10:29:35" | (9, 11, 13, 8)
```

I tried to use `GROUP BY` with `ARRAY_AGG` to get the latest timestamp for each Name but it doesn't work because `GROUP BY` can't be used on an ARRAY type field.

How can I get the result that I want? Using Standard SQL.

Comment: There are multiple questions similar to you in SO, as an example https://stackoverflow.com/a/53382218/1031958, Do a bit of research and share the latest SQL you are using if you still need help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aggregate into a struct with ARRAY_AGG, then extract the fields:

```
SELECT
  Name,
  ARRAY_AGG(
    STRUCT(LastLogin, FavoriteNumbers)
    ORDER BY LastLogin DESC LIMIT 1
  )[OFFSET(0)].*
FROM dataset.table
GROUP BY Name
```